# Create PDU for Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, sms, pdu

I am currently writing and application, that is sending/receiving SMS messages.

For unit-testing purposes I need to create PDU programmatically. Decoding is quite easy:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    /* Get all messages contained in the Intent*/
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdusObj[i]);
    }
}
```

Is there any appropriate way to **create** PDU programamtically?

Comment: I'm not clear why you are unit testing the PDU since that is handled by Android. Don't you really want to just test you logic and not googles?

Comment: It is not a matter of whose logic is it. I am testing my application works correctly even if the environment (Mobile Service Provider or device) is not. Currently, I am testing using the straight-forward approach and I would like to start a broadcast 'android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED' with Intent and proper bundles attached to test my code works correctly.

Comment: @ibo.ezhe Did you ever successfuly Create a PDU programtically that could be decoded with the createFromPDU() method? I've been dancing around this problem for a week. I have the same question with 50 bounty on it - http://stackoverflow.com/q/12335642/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically PDUs are hardcoded in the code. Similar to this:

```
String pdu = "07914151551512f2040B916105551511f100006060605130308A04D4F29C0E";
SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(HexDump.hexStringToByteArray(pdu));
```

[Here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/idea133/tests/telephonytests/src/com/android/internal/telephony/GsmSmsTest.java) a complete example on how to do this.

Now, you're gonna ask me "where can I find a PDU for testing?" You generate it. For example, you can use [this](http://www.smartposition.nl/resources/sms_pdu.html#PDU_CONVERTER) online service.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: The little green checkmark makes it automatic, yes. And thanks!