# can I send "SMS received intent"?

Tags: android, sms

Title is obvious. Can I send "SMS received intent" on the android phone? In other words, virtually receive custom SMS to fake some SMS receivers.

Comment: FYI I believe this is a system intent, and you cannot broadcast it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create fake SMS (GMS type) so built-in catch like real message. Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/1050058)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
        "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");
intent.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
intent.putExtra("pdus", new Object[] { pdu });
intent.putExtra("format", "3gpp");
context.startService(intent);
```

Comment: I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED cmp=com.android.mms/.transaction.SmsReceiverService (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10045

Comment: I have this permission in manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />