# Send SMS to local android phone without SIM card?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. One function I want to achieve is to send SMS message to the phone itself. I thought about two ways to do it:

1. Get the phone number of this phone and send a message to itself. This should be easy.
2. If there is a internal representation of the phone itself that does not need a SIM card and real phone number, it would be more convenient.

Does anyone know any information on the second method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fake the intent that signals the phone it received a message. It's been asked before, see here: [can I send "SMS received intent"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489716/can-i-send-sms-received-intent)

The answer on that question in turn links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/1569315) (example).