# Populate SMS in android without a GSM connection

Tags: android, sms

Is there a way I can create SMSs on an Android for testing an App that I'm creating ? This is on an actual phone. I believe there's a way to do it on an Emulator. Is it possible on the phone itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my snippet to generate SMS message

```
    private static void createFakeSms(Context context, String sender,
        String body) {
    byte[] pdu = null;
    byte[] scBytes = PhoneNumberUtils
            .networkPortionToCalledPartyBCD("0000000000");
    byte[] senderBytes = PhoneNumberUtils
            .networkPortionToCalledPartyBCD(sender);
    int lsmcs = scBytes.length;
    byte[] dateBytes = new byte[7];
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    dateBytes[0] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
    dateBytes[1] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
    dateBytes[2] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
    dateBytes[3] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
    dateBytes[4] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
    dateBytes[5] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
    dateBytes[6] = reverseByte((byte) ((calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar
            .get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000 * 15)));
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bo.write(lsmcs);
        bo.write(scBytes);
        bo.write(0x04);
        bo.write((byte) sender.length());
        bo.write(senderBytes);
        bo.write(0x00);
        bo.write(0x00); // encoding: 0 for default 7bit
        bo.write(dateBytes);
        try {
            String sReflectedClassName = "com.android.internal.telephony.GsmAlphabet";
            Class cReflectedNFCExtras = Class.forName(sReflectedClassName);
            Method stringToGsm7BitPacked = cReflectedNFCExtras.getMethod(
                    "stringToGsm7BitPacked", new Class[] { String.class });
            stringToGsm7BitPacked.setAccessible(true);
            byte[] bodybytes = (byte[]) stringToGsm7BitPacked.invoke(null,
                    body);
            bo.write(bodybytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        pdu = bo.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
            "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");
    intent.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    intent.putExtra("pdus", new Object[] { pdu });
    intent.putExtra("format", "3gpp");
    context.startService(intent);
}

private static byte reverseByte(byte b) {
    return (byte) ((b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4);
}
```

It'll invoke new SMS. Others problem you can see more at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/1050058)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Send an email to your phone number with the appropriate email gateway for your carrier (ie  5555555555@mobile.att.net)

The email will go to your phone as an SMS message.

Comment: I want a solution when there is no SIM, hence no phone number