# How to emulate SMS receiving at Android?

Tags: android, sms

I have the following code to receive SMS by my application:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    ...
```

In order to test it, I have to send an SMS with telnet (and I can do nothing with Android x86).

Can I call this `onReceive` programmatically for ex., when button is pressed or application is started? What kind of parameters should I pass (i.e. where tel number should be? text of the message etc.)?

**Upd**. I found this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/604388. If I follow that code, i.e.:

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
                "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");
context.startService(intent);
```

then standard event is fired (i.e. message is received by standard android Messaging app), but my code at `onReceive` doesn't work.
If I replace it with:

```
// intent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
//                "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");

context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

then my code at `onReceive` works, but not standard android app. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: were u able to test it

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? DDMS can emulate SMS messages, calles and locations. It's integrated with Eclipse set up for Android development and Android studio. You can find it at:

Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: No, it doesn't help since I want to "send" message automatically, without telnet or DDMS.

Comment: @LA_ were u able to test it