# How to allow other applications to process SMS after calling abortBroadcast?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver`, which listens for incoming SMS. Once SMS received, mt application processes it and call `abortBroadcast`. Notification is created. Once user reacts on the notification (and, let's say choose 'No' there), I would like to allow other applications to process the SMS (like it is just received). How can I do it?

Comment: Hopefully the SMS broadcast cannot be spoofed by regular applications, courtesy of some system-level permission. Hence, I hope that what you want is not possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is the code there - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/604388 - called SMS spoofing?

Comment: Locally, yes, though it has some implementation flaws.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare, please post your reply as the answer, so I will be able to accept it.