# Android - send fake SMS to local phone on KitKat

Tags: android, sms, send, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a Nexus 5 running KitKat with no SIM card (work phone etc). I'm trying to create an app that will send a fake SMS locally to the device so I can demonstrate SMS receiver behavior but I can't get it to work. I've implemented the code phone in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335642/create-pdu-for-android-that-works-with-smsmessage-createfrompdu-gsm-3gpp/12338541#12338541) topic, which others have said work fine for them, but when I run it I get the generic "no matching service error":

Unable to start service intent act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED cmp=com.android.mms/.transaction.SMSReceiverService

At first I thought the issue might have been the fact that the phone was using Hangouts but switching the default app to Textra didn't help. So I did more digging and found the "Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat" blog post which talked about the new intents and behavior and it looks like on KitKat they want you to use the default SMS provider, so is there a way to use this to send an SMS to the local phone? I didn't see any examples and the API makes no mention of the capability.