# Testing sending sms pdu on android

Tags: android, sms, pdu, smspdu

I would like to test receiving and sending sms pdus from my app
Is there a way in Kitkat, 4.4, to do this?

Previously there was a way to "fake" receive and sms: [Create PDU for Android that works with SmsMessage.createFromPdu() (GSM 3gpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335642/create-pdu-for-android-that-works-with-smsmessage-createfrompdu-gsm-3gpp)

But, this does not seem to work anymore.

Is there a workaround?
As sending actual sms directly for testing is not an option as it will be costly, especially in development stage.
As far as I know emulator does not work with pdu sending, and I need to test the pdus themselves