# Android SMS App features

Tags: android, sms

Hi want to do an app that can send and receive text messages I checked out the documentation for it but I couldn't find the answer to this question. Is there a way to make is send SMS through wifi (without a sim card)? so tablets and devices without simcards can use it? and yes it has to be sms because I want to be able to send it to people that doesnt have the app

Comment: Some answers on this can be found on http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22579/how-can-i-forward-texts-to-my-tablet-and-reply-back

Comment: Im looking for code solutions not for other apps

Comment: First, take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335642/create-pdu-for-android-that-works-with-smsmessage-createfrompdu-gsm-3gpp/12338541#12338541. Also, see https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2419125.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a text from your app without a sim card through wifi, you can implement a SMS Gateway API BUT, but the receiver must be using a SIM Card.

You can do this using Nexmo. 
After signing up for the free trial, you will receive an api_key, api_secret, number (from), and will be allowed to test out this with up to 10 whitelisted numbers.

You can use Nexmo's API by making a simple HTTP call to: https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?

Include the required parameters (**api_key**, **api_secret**, **from**, **to**, **text**) and the optional parameters you choose (if any) and you are ready to send your first text.

Also, our Android SDK is coming out soon so make sure to keep an eye out for that!

*Full disclosure, I work at Nexmo*

For more information on how to implement this you can check out the docs [here](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/send-message)